# AWS SSM Patch Manager - Update Dev and then apply SAME updates to Prod after grace period

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, automation, windows-update, aws-ssm

I apologize if this has been answered before. The question is very specific, I hope I explained it correctly. I may be going about this whole thing the wrong way so please share any knowledge that may be helpful.

**Scenario:**

We have 2 accounts: Prod and Dev. We have multiple Windows machines running in each account and we want to create an automated updated cycle for those machines.

The requirement is that we first apply updates to the machines in the Dev account and only after a grace period of 10 days, in which we tested the servers thoroughly to make sure the updates didn't break anything, we update the Prod instances with the **exact same updates**. We simply to do not want to accidentally get a newer update that was released during the grace period.

Does this make sense? Can this be achieved easily with the patch manager or should we try to somehow fetch the updates from the dev machines after the grace period and update from there?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom baseline. you can setup an auto approve delay of 10 days so anything that was released in the 10 day grace period will not be installed. More info in this AWS document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-patch-baselines.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).